# Pegar o uso da CPU em porcentagem

Tags: java

Como pegar o uso da CPU em porcentagem no java?

O mais próximo que cheguei foi esse código que tentei adaptar, mas apresenta resultados diferentes com relação ao gerenciador de tarefas do Windows

segue abaixo

```
package teste;

import java.io.File;
 import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
// import java.lang.management.Operating

    SystemMXBean;
     import java.lang.reflect.Method;
     import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;
     import java.lang.management.RuntimeMXBean;
     import java.io.*;
     import java.net.*;
     import java.util.*;
     import java.io.LineNumberReader;
     import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
    import com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean;
    import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
    import java.util.Random;

    public class Teste {

        public static void printUsage(Runtime runtime)
         {
         long total, free, used;
         int mb = 1024*1024;

         total = runtime.totalMemory();
         free = runtime.freeMemory();
         used = total - free;
         System.out.println("\nTotal Memory: " + total / mb + "MB");
         System.out.println(" Memory Used: " + used / mb + "MB");
         System.out.println(" Memory Free: " + free / mb + "MB");
         System.out.println("Percent Used: " + ((double)used/(double)total)*100 + "%");
         System.out.println("Percent Free: " + ((double)free/(double)total)*100 + "%");
        }
        public static void log(Object message)
             {
                System.out.println(message);
             }

            public static int calcCPU(long cpuStartTime, long elapsedStartTime, int cpuCount)
            {
                 long end = System.nanoTime();
                 long totalAvailCPUTime = cpuCount * (end-elapsedStartTime);
                 long totalUsedCPUTime = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean().getCurrentThreadCpuTime()-cpuStartTime;
                 //log("Total CPU Time:" + totalUsedCPUTime + " ns.");
                 //log("Total Avail CPU Time:" + totalAvailCPUTime + " ns.");
                 float per = ((float)totalUsedCPUTime*100)/(float)totalAvailCPUTime;
                 log( per);
                 return (int)per;
            }

            static boolean isPrime(int n)
            {
         // 2 is the smallest prime
                if (n <= 2)
                {
                    return n == 2;
                }
         // even numbers other than 2 are not prime
                if (n % 2 == 0)
                {
                    return false;
                }
         // check odd divisors from 3
         // to the square root of n
             for (int i = 3, end = (int)Math.sqrt(n); i <= end; i += 2)
             {
                if (n % i == 0)
             {
             return false;
            }
            }
     return true;
    }
        public static void main(String [] args)
        {
                int mb = 1024*1024;
                int gb = 1024*1024*1024;
                 /* PHYSICAL MEMORY USAGE */
                 System.out.println("\n**** Sizes in Mega Bytes ****\n");
                com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean operatingSystemMXBean = (com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean)ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();
                //RuntimeMXBean runtimeMXBean = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();
                //operatingSystemMXBean = (com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean) ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();
                com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean os = (com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean)
                java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();
                long physicalMemorySize = os.getTotalPhysicalMemorySize();
                System.out.println("PHYSICAL MEMORY DETAILS \n");
                System.out.println("total physical memory : " + physicalMemorySize / mb + "MB ");
                long physicalfreeMemorySize = os.getFreePhysicalMemorySize();
                System.out.println("total free physical memory : " + physicalfreeMemorySize / mb + "MB");
                /* DISC SPACE DETAILS */
                File diskPartition = new File("C:");
                File diskPartition1 = new File("D:");
                File diskPartition2 = new File("E:");
                long totalCapacity = diskPartition.getTotalSpace() / gb;
                long totalCapacity1 = diskPartition1.getTotalSpace() / gb;
                double freePartitionSpace = diskPartition.getFreeSpace() / gb;
                double freePartitionSpace1 = diskPartition1.getFreeSpace() / gb;
                double freePartitionSpace2 = diskPartition2.getFreeSpace() / gb;
                double usablePatitionSpace = diskPartition.getUsableSpace() / gb;
                System.out.println("\n**** Sizes in Giga Bytes ****\n");
                System.out.println("DISC SPACE DETAILS \n");
                //System.out.println("Total C partition size : " + totalCapacity + "GB");
                //System.out.println("Usable Space : " + usablePatitionSpace + "GB");
                System.out.println("Free Space in drive C: : " + freePartitionSpace + "GB");
                System.out.println("Free Space in drive D:  : " + freePartitionSpace1 + "GB");
                System.out.println("Free Space in drive E: " + freePartitionSpace2 + "GB");
                if(freePartitionSpace <= totalCapacity%10 || freePartitionSpace1 <= totalCapacity1%10)
                {
                    System.out.println(" !!!alert!!!!");
                }
                else
                    System.out.println("no alert");

                Runtime runtime;
                byte[] bytes;
                System.out.println("\n \n**MEMORY DETAILS  ** \n");
                // Print initial memory usage.
                runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
                printUsage(runtime);

                // Allocate a 1 Megabyte and print memory usage
                bytes = new byte[1024*1024];
                printUsage(runtime);

                bytes = null;
                // Invoke garbage collector to reclaim the allocated memory.
                runtime.gc();

                // Wait 5 seconds to give garbage collector a chance to run
                try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return;
                }

                // Total memory will probably be the same as the second printUsage call,
                // but the free memory should be about 1 Megabyte larger if garbage
                // collection kicked in.
                printUsage(runtime);
                for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
                         {
                             long start = System.nanoTime();
                            // log(start);
                            //number of available processors;
                             int cpuCount = ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean().getAvailableProcessors();
                             Random random = new Random(start);
                             int seed = Math.abs(random.nextInt());
                             log("\n \n CPU USAGE DETAILS \n\n");
                             log("Starting Test with " + cpuCount + " CPUs and random number:" + seed);
                             int primes = 10000;
                             //
                             long startCPUTime = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean().getCurrentThreadCpuTime();
                             start = System.nanoTime();
                             while(primes != 0)
                             {
                                if(isPrime(seed))
                                {
                                    primes--;
                                }
                                seed++;

                            }
                             float cpuPercent = calcCPU(startCPUTime, start, cpuCount);
                             log("CPU USAGE : " + cpuPercent + " % ");


                             try
                             {
                                 Thread.sleep(1000);
                             }
                             catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            }

                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } 
                catch (Exception ignored) { }
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sua variável `os` contém um `com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean`. Essa classe oferece um método `getSystemCpuLoad()` que retorna um `double` entre 0 e 1 indicando o uso de CPU ou então -1 se ele não conseguir medir o uso de CPU. Multiplique esse valor de 0 a 1 por 100, e terá um valor em porcentagem.

O valor total de memória você deve obter do `OperatingSystemMXBean`. O valor dado pela classe `Runtime` é referente apenas à memória da JVM.

O código que você tem possui um `while` para testar se um monte de números aleatórios são primos e com isso tentar manter a CPU ocupada para depois medir o uso de CPU. Isso também significa que (1) ele estaria bagunçando com qualquer medição de consumo de CPU que você se propusesse a fazer, (2) que qualquer medição feita seria artificial e não corresponderia ao que acontece no seu sistema e (3) que o código como estava era inútil para medir-se o consumo real de CPU em uma situação real onde você precise disso. Além disso, o método `calcCPU` se propõe a fazer uma implementação caseira e incorreta da medição de consumo de CPU.

Apaguei do seu código toda essa tralha de gerar números primos e também o método `calcCPU`, delegando apenas ao `OperatingSystemMXBean` as medições. Também dei uma mexida e uma reorganizada no código como um todo. Ficou assim:

```
package teste;

import java.io.File;
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Teste {

    private static final long KB = 1024;
    private static final long MB = 1024 * KB;
    private static final long GB = 1024 * MB;
    private static final long TB = 1024 * GB;
    private static final com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean OS_BEAN =
            (com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean) ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();

    public static void log(Object message) {
        System.out.println(message);
    }

    private static void sleep1Sec() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // Ignore.
        }
    }

    private static String formatDouble(double d) {
        NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(new Locale("PT", "BR"));
        nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
        return nf.format(d);
    }

    private static String formatBytes(long b) {
        return b >= TB ? formatDouble(b / (double) TB) + " TB"
                : b >= GB ? formatDouble(b / (double) GB) + " GB"
                : b >= MB ? formatDouble(b / (double) MB) + " MB"
                : b >= KB ? formatDouble(b / (double) KB) + " KB"
                : b + " bytes";
    }

    public static void printMemoryUsage() {
        //Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
        //long jvmTotal = r.totalMemory();
        //long jvmFree = r.freeMemory();
        //long jvmUsed = jvmTotal - jvmFree;
        long total = OS_BEAN.getTotalPhysicalMemorySize();
        long free = OS_BEAN.getFreePhysicalMemorySize();
        long used = total - free;
        System.out.println("Total Memory: " + formatBytes(total));
        System.out.println("Memory Used: " + formatBytes(used));
        System.out.println("Memory Free: " + formatBytes(free));
        System.out.println("Percent Used: " + formatDouble(100 * used / (double) total) + "%");
        System.out.println("Percent Free: " + formatDouble(100 * free / (double) total) + "%");
    }

    public static void printDiskUsage(String disk) {
        File diskPartition = new File(disk + ":");
        long total = diskPartition.getTotalSpace();
        long free = diskPartition.getFreeSpace();
        long usable = diskPartition.getUsableSpace();
        System.out.println("Total space in drive " + disk + ": " + formatBytes(total));
        System.out.println("Free space in drive " + disk + ": " + formatBytes(free));
        System.out.println("Usable space in drive " + disk + ": " + formatBytes(usable));
    }

    public static void printDiskUsage(String... disks) {
        for (String disk : disks) {
            printDiskUsage(disk);
        }
    }

    public static void printProcessorUsage() {
        int cpuCount = OS_BEAN.getAvailableProcessors();
        double load = OS_BEAN.getSystemCpuLoad();
        String formattedLoad = load >= 0 ? formatDouble(load * 100) + "%" : "unknown";
        log("With " + cpuCount + " CPUs usage is " + formattedLoad + ".");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printMemoryUsage();
        printDiskUsage("C", "D", "E");

        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            printProcessorUsage();
            sleep1Sec();
        }
    }
}
```

O código acima para mim funciona, mas para ser sincero, ele não fornece um número igual a medição feita pelo Windows, embora com certeza os números sejam parecidos dentro de alguma margem de erro razoável.

Comment: Cara, fantástico entendi muita coisa mais do que em 3 semanas de pesquisa, não sei mesmo como agradecer. Obrigado mesmo por ajudar espero um dia ter a metade do conhecimento que você tem. São pessoas como você que ajudam o próximo que faz o mundo melhor. Novamente obrigado meu amigo

Comment: @SávioSantos Se essa resposta resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique a vontade para comentar. 